# Como calcular divisão apenas utilizando a operação subtração?

Tags: python, matemática

Estou tentando colocar uma linha de comando que faz divisão a partir da subtração dentro de um dicionario mas estaria ocasionando erro, saberia aonde eu estou errando?

```
x = float(x)
y = float(y)
num = 0
if y != 0:
    if (x>0) and (y>0):
        def Divisão (x, y):
            while (x >= y):
                x = x - y
                num = num + 1
            return num
        print(f"Seu resultado é: {Divisão(x, y)}")
    elif (x>0) and (y<0):
        y = -(y)
        def Divisão(x, y):

            while (x>0):
                x = x - y
                num = num - 1
            return num
        print(f"Seu resultado é: {Divisão(x, y)}")        
    elif (x<0) and (y>0):
        x = -(x)
        def Divisão(x, y):
            while (x>0):
                x = x - y
                num = num - 1
            return num                
        print(f"Seu resultado é: {Divisão(x, y)}")
    else:
        x= -(x)
        y= -(y)
        def Divisão (x, y):

            while (x>0):
                x = x - y
                num = num + 1
            return num
        print(f"Seu resultado é: {Divisão(x, y)}")
```

Comment: Saudações XiruXim, se alguma das respostas respondeu a sua pergunta, considere aceitá-la. Veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/5878) e [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

A palavra reservada `def` serve para [criar uma função](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions). No seu código você está criando uma versão diferente da função para cada condição do seu `if`, mas não precisa disso.

Uma forma mais simples é colocar estas condições dentro da função, e defini-la apenas uma vez. Exemplo:

```
def dividir(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError('Não pode dividir por zero')

    sinal = 1
    # ajusta os valores e o sinal do resultado
    if x < 0:
        x = -x
        sinal *= -1
    if y < 0:
        y = -y
        sinal *= -1

    result = 0
    while x >= y:
        x -= y
        result += 1
    return result * sinal
```

Primeiro faço uma verificação para evitar divisão por zero. Depois eu faço as verificações sobre o sinal de x e y. Repare que se x for negativo eu inverto o sinal de 1 para -1, pois assim eu consigo ajustar o resultado final. A mesma coisa é feita para y.

Por fim, faço o loop com as subtrações, e o resultado final é ajustado de acordo com o sinal.

Desta forma a função já trata todos os casos e você não precisa defini-la quatro vezes.

Repare também na sintaxe `x -= y`, que é equivalente a `x = x - y` (assim como `sinal *= -1` é o mesmo que `sinal = sinal * -1`, e `result += 1` é o mesmo que `result = result + 1` - atenção: [nem sempre essas duas formas são equivalentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402702/112052), mas para este caso específico, o resultado  é o mesmo).

---

Rodando o seu código, obtive esse erro:

> ```
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment
> ```

Isso acontece porque `num` foi declarada fora da função `Divisão`, mas você está usando-a dentro da função. Uma solução seria inicializá-la dentro da função:

```
def Divisão (x, y):
    num = 0 # <--- aqui
    while (x >= y):
        x = x - y
        num = num + 1
    return num
```

Pois assim você cria uma variável local `num` (que não é o mesmo `num` que foi criado fora da função).

Ou você pode indicar que quer usar o `num` global (o que está fora da função):

```
def Divisão (x, y):
    global num
    while (x >= y):
        x = x - y
        num = num + 1
    return num
```

Mas nesse caso, ainda acho que a melhor solução é definir a função apenas uma vez, como já sugeri acima.

Comment: Sim, eu também apliquei este método e funciono, outro que testei e funciono tambem foi por a minha variável num, dentro do def e no print. Muito obrigado !!

Comment: @XiruXin Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 2):

Você não postou o erro que lhe dá, no entanto olhando para o seu código penso que não deveria estar a colocar tantas funções `Divisão()`, remova isso. 
Vou lhe dar o primeiro bloco de `if` para ver como fica:

```
if (x>0) and (y>0):
        while (x >= y):
            x = x - y
            num = num + 1
    print(f"Seu resultado é: {num}")
```

Moral da história: você só deveria criar a função `Divisão()` se ela podesse ser usada pelo outros blocos de `if`/`else`, como no seu caso cada bloco precisa de uma função diferente simplesmente compute o resultado sem recorrer a funções. Penso que isso lhe estaria a causar problemas devido a você estar a referir-se à variável `num` antes de a declarar ou passar como parametro para a função.