# Qual a diferença de i += 2 e i = i + 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis

Eu estava vendo, tem gente que fala que é diferente e tem quem fala que é a mesma coisa. Estou confuso. Eles são diferentes ou fazem a mesma coisa?

Comment: Nenhuma diferença no resultado. A primeira forma é apenas mais compacta.

Comment: O primeiro chama o método `__iadd__`; o segundo o método `__add__`. O resultado produzido é o mesmo, para número inteiro, caso nenhum desses métodos seja sobrescrito.

Comment: A unica coisa que já ouvi  falar é que  o  metod de auto incremento é mais rápido  por não  ter que alocar duas  vezes o  espaço  em  memoria, tirando isso não há diferença e  talvez seu  impacto  na peformance não  seja assim  tão  grande, dependendo  do  tamanho do processamento

Comment: Eu fiz os dois jeitos e deu resultados diferentes em duas listas.
O primeiro jeito:
`a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b += [1, 2, 3]
print(a) # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
print(b) # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`

O segundo jeito:

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b = b + [1, 2, 3]
print(a) # [1, 2, 3]
print(b) # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu encontrei algo interessante no PEP-203 que é onde eles propoem o *augmented assignment* (i += 2):

> A idéia por trás da atribuição aumentada em Python é que não é apenas uma maneira mais fácil de escrever a prática comum de armazenar o resultado de uma operação binária em seu operando à esquerda, mas também uma maneira de o operando da esquerda em questão saber que deve operar em si mesmo, em vez de criar uma cópia modificada de si mesmo.

Fonte: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/#id8

Na minha conclusão, uma importante diferença é que na atribuição aumentada poderia não criar uma cópia modificada de si mesmo, para fins de otimização.

Comment: Sua conclusão do resumo não está correta, e pode ser perigosa. Para objetos imutáveis - o que inclui os tipos numéricos do Python, a atribuição aumentada *cria um novo objeto* da mesma forma. Para objetos mutáveis, como listas, e logo dicionários (a operação de "+" com dicionários foi aceita para o Python 3.9), essa atribuição modifica o próŕio objeto.

Comment: Editado! Obrigado pelo comentário!

Comment: Editada a resposta para refletir o fato de que += *pode* evitar a criação de um objeto, não quer dizer que *vai* evitar (nem que deva obrigatoriamente evitar).

Comment: @epx sim, mas isso não é válido para strings como você sugeriu na sua resposta.

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/satwikkansal/do-you-really-think-you-know-strings-in-python-fnxh8mtha sugere que é válido sim.

Comment: @epx Em que parte?

Answer (score 16):

Conforme já comentado, não haverá diferença no resultado.

Porém vamos fazer uma depuração simples do seu código:

#### Usando i += 2

```
from dis import dis

code = '''
i=1
i+=2

'''

print(dis(code))

 2       0 LOAD_CONST        0 (1)
         3 STORE_NAME        0 (i)

 3       6 LOAD_NAME         0 (i)
         9 LOAD_CONST        1 (2)
         12 INPLACE_ADD
         13 STORE_NAME       0 (i)
         16 LOAD_CONST       2 (None)
         19 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

#### Usando i = i + 2

```
from dis import dis

code = '''
i=1
i=i+2

'''

print(dis(code))

 2       0 LOAD_CONST        0 (1)
         3 STORE_NAME        0 (i)

 3       6 LOAD_NAME         0 (i)
         9 LOAD_CONST        1 (2)
         12 BINARY_ADD
         13 STORE_NAME       0 (i)
         16 LOAD_CONST       2 (None)
         19 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

**Observe que a única diferença é entre as instruções `INPLACE_ADD` e  `BINARY_ADD`**

Traduzindo, via google translate, a pergunta:

[When is “i += x” different from “i = i + x” in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Quando é "i + = x" diferente de "i = i + x" em Python?

Chegaremos a esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376520/10301489), traduzida via google translate:

> Isso depende inteiramente do objeto `i`.
>
> `+=`chama o [__iadd__method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) (se existir - percorrendo `__add__`se
>   não existir) enquanto `+`chama o [__add__method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)¹ ou o
>   [__radd__method em alguns casos](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)¹ .
>
> De uma perspectiva da API, `__iadd__`é suposto ser usado para
>   modificar objetos mutáveis no lugar (retornando o objeto que foi
>   mutado), ao passo que `__add__`deve retornar uma nova instância de
>   algo. Para objetos *imutáveis* , os dois métodos retornam uma nova
>   instância, mas `__iadd__`colocarão a nova instância no namespace atual
>   com o mesmo nome da instância antiga. Isso é por que
>
> ```
> i = 1
> i += 1
> ```
>
> parece incrementar `i`. Na realidade, você obtém um novo inteiro e o
>   atribui "em cima de" `i`  -- perdendo uma referência ao inteiro
>   antigo. Nesse caso, `i += 1` é exatamente o mesmo que `i = i + 1`.
>
> Mas, com a maioria dos objetos mutáveis, é uma história diferente:
>
> Como um exemplo concreto:
>
> ```
> a = [1, 2, 3]
> b = a
> b += [1, 2, 3]
> print a  #[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
> print b  #[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
> ```
>
> comparado com:
>
> ```
> a = [1, 2, 3]
> b = a
> b = b + [1, 2, 3]
> print a #[1, 2, 3]
> print b #[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
> ```
>
> note como no primeiro exemplo, uma vez `b` e `a` referenciam o mesmo
>   objeto, quando  uso `+=` em `b`, ele realmente muda `b`(e `a` vê a
>   mudança também - Afinal de contas, ele está referenciando `a` na mesma
>   lista).
>
> No segundo caso, no entanto, quando o faço `b = b + [1, 2, 3`], isso
>   leva a lista que `b` está fazendo referência e `a` concatena com uma
>   nova lista `[1, 2, 3]`. Em seguida, ele armazena a lista concatenada
>   no namespace atual como `b` -- sem considerar o que `b` era a linha
>   anterior.
>
> ¹ Na expressão `x + y`, se `x.__add__`não for implementada ou se
>   `x.__add__(y)`retorna `NotImplemented` e  `x` e `y` têm *tipos
>   diferentes* , em seguida, `x + y` tenta chamar [y.**radd**(x)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__).
>   Então, no caso de você ter `foo_instance += bar_instance`
>
> se `Foo` não implementar `__add__`ou `__iadd__` então o resultado aqui
>   é o mesmo que
>
> ```
> foo_instance = bar_instance.__radd__(bar_instance, foo_instance)
> ```
>
> ² Na expressão `foo_instance + bar_instance`,
>   `bar_instance.__radd__`será tentado antes `foo_instance.__add__` se o
>   tipo de `bar_instance` for uma subclasse do tipo de `foo_instance(eg
>   issubclass(Bar, Foo))`. O racional para isso é porque `Bar` é em certo
>   sentido um objeto "de alto nível" que `Foo` assim `Bar` deve obter a
>   opção de substituir  o comportamento de `Foo`.

Answer (score -1):

No caso de um número não tem muita diferença, mas se fosse um tipo mais complexo, pode ser que += fosse mais eficiente que + pelo fato de não precisar criar um novo objeto.

Por exemplo, supondo que seja o tipo String,

```
a = a + b
```

na verdade o que acontece nos bastidores é:

```
tmp = a + b
a = tmp
```

A string "tmp" é completamente nova, e por um breve período coexiste com "a" na memória.

Já a expressão

```
a += b
```

pode ser otimizada para mexer diretamente nas "entranhas" da string "a" a fim de anexar o conteúdo de "b", pois está claro que o valor original de "a" não interessa mais.

Mesmo a string sendo um tipo imutável no Python e em muitas outras linguagens, este é um caso em que ele pode ser mutável internamente.

Citei o tipo string apenas como exemplo, ele pode ou não tomar partido dessa diferença entre operadores. O fato é que o Python permite que você faça esse tipo de otimização ao implementar seu tipo ou sua classe, implementando o método __iadd__ além de __add__, supondo é claro que a operacão "somar" faz sentido para ela.

Comment: Como é possível obter uma string mutável internamente? Não entendi essa parte.

Comment: Isso é lá dentro da implementação; para consumo humano ela é imutável.

Comment: Em Java tem uns negócios tipo StringIO que fazem papel de string mutável, deve ter algo semelhante para Pyhthon.

Comment: Tem fontes que embasam essas informações? Eu já analisei várias vezes a fundo o fonte em C do Python e não lembro de já ter visto referências dessa possível mutabilidade da *string*, nem de como isso poderia influenciar na diferença na chamada dos operadores.

Comment: Eu disse que uma implementação PODE otimizar, discriminando entre os operadores += e +. Se o Python (ou a implementação C de Python; tem pypy, tem IronPython, tem outras) faz isso, está fora do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Além do que, usei o tipo nativo String como exemplo. Você pode criar um tipo novo, ou uma classe, e implementar \_\_iadd\_\_ de forma otimizada em relação a \_\_add\_\_.

Comment: Bom, então manterei o negativo; se a pergunta é "como isso funciona no Python", não vejo como útil uma resposta do tipo "não sei como é no Python, mas poderia ser assim..."

Comment: Está equivocada essa conclusão e o teste é simples é só manipular as referências para um string: 1) cria-se uma string chamada `a`: `>>> a = "teste"`. 2) Faz-se `b` uma referência a `a`: `>>> b = a`. 3) Se `+=` modifica a estrutura interna da string não criando novo objeto, então conclui-se que se fizermos `>>> a += " mais"`, `a` e `b` continuarão a referenciar  o mesmo objeto e tanto `>>> print(a)` e `>>> print(b)` imprimirão o mesmo resultado. 4) Conclusão `>>> print(a)` imprimiu `teste mais` e `>>> print(b)` imprimiu `teste` implicando que `>>> a += " mais"` criou um novo objeto em `a`.

Comment: String em Python é um tipo imutável. O seu teste não prova que a otimização não é feita. Qualquer implementação decente do tipo String implementa contagem interna de referências e copy-on-write. A única coisa que seu teste prova é que a implementação está ok, o que não é exatamente numa novidade.

Comment: Achei este artigo: https://www.codementor.io/satwikkansal/do-you-really-think-you-know-strings-in-python-fnxh8mtha , trecho de interesse: += is actually faster than + for concatenating more than two strings because the first string (example, s1 for s1 += s2 + s3) is not destroyed while calculating the complete string.

Answer (score -4):

Não há diferença quanto aos resultados, apenas no modo de escrita, sendo uma mais resumida e outra não. Desse modo, ambas podem ser usadas, pois  não haverá alteração em quaisquer resultados.

Comment: Monteiro, convido-te ler a resposta do Luiz Augusto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402702/5878