# objeto1 += objeto2 é diferente objeto1= objeto1 + objeto2 no python(3.8)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, operadores

`objeto1 += objeto2` e `objeto1= objeto1 + objeto2` dão resultados diferentes apesar das duas formas parecerem equivalentes. Alguém poderia me explicar o que não estou percebendo?

```
class f():
    def __init__(self,caixa=[]):
        self.caixa= caixa

class g(f):
    def __init__(self,caixa=[]):
        super().__init__(caixa)

    def inicializarFs(self, listaFs):
        self.listaFs= listaFs
        self.listaFs[0].caixa= self.listaFs[0].caixa + ['ok']

             

a= f()
b= f()
c= f()
d= g()

d.inicializarFs([a,b])

print(a.caixa)
print(b.caixa)
print(c.caixa)
```

saída console :

```
['ok']
[]
[]
```

PORÉM:

```
class f():
    def __init__(self,caixa=[]):
        self.caixa= caixa

class g(f):
    def __init__(self,caixa=[]):
        super().__init__(caixa)

    def inicializarFs(self, listaFs):
        self.listaFs= listaFs
        self.listaFs[0].caixa+= ['ok'] # linha modificada em relação a anterior

a= f()
b= f()
c= f()
d= g()

d.inicializarFs([a,b])

print(a.caixa)
print(b.caixa)
print(c.caixa)
```

saída console :

```
['ok']
['ok']
['ok']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/823878/4802649

Comment: Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu (apenas uma delas) e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que acontece é uma combinação de dois comportamentos distintos.

O primeiro é o que está descrito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402702/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/823878). Leia os links para mais detalhes, mas resumindo, o operador `+=` modifica a própria lista, enquanto que `lista = lista + outra_lista` cria outra lista e atribui à variável `lista`.

Um jeito de ver essa diferença é atribuindo a lista à outra variável e modificando a original:

```
x = [1]
copia = x
x += [2]
print(x, copia) # [1, 2] [1, 2]

x = [1]
copia = x
x = x + [2]
print(x, copia) # [1, 2] [1]
```

No primeiro caso, a lista foi modificada pelo operador `+=`, por isso tanto `x` quanto `copia` são modificadas (já que ambos apontam para a mesma lista).

No segundo caso, é criada uma nova lista e atribuída a `x`. Mas `copia` continua apontando para a lista original, e portanto não é modificada.

---

O segundo comportamento em questão é o descrito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240652/112052). Basicamente, o argumento padrão é avaliado no momento em que a função é definida. Ou seja, em:

```
def __init__(self, caixa=[]):
```

**Não** é criada uma nova lista vazia a cada vez que `__init__` é chamado. Esta lista é criada apenas uma vez, quando a função é definida, e todas as instâncias de `f` apontarão para essa mesma lista.

Então no seu caso, tanto `a.caixa` quanto `b.caixa` e `c.caixa` estão apontando para a mesma lista.

Depois, em `inicializarFs` você está alterando a `caixa` do primeiro elemento de `listaFs` (que no caso, é `a`).

Quando você usa `+=`, está alterando a própria lista `a.caixa`. E como `a.caixa.`, `b.caixa` e `c.caixa` estão apontando para a mesma lista, ao alterar `a.caixa`, as listas `b.caixa` e `c.caixa` também são afetadas (afinal, todas apontam para a mesma lista).

Já quando você faz `self.listaFs[0].caixa = self.listaFs[0].caixa + ['ok']`, está criando uma nova lista e atribuindo a `a.caixa`, enquanto `b.caixa` e `c.caixa` continuam apontando para a lista original, que ainda está vazia.

---

Para que as listas sejam independentes (ou seja, que sempre seja criada uma nova lista para cada instância), uma alternativa é fazer o que foi sugerido em uma das perguntas já *linkadas* (mais precisamente [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240667/112052)). Em vez de colocar a lista vazia na definição da função, crie uma nova dentro dela:

```
def __init__(self, caixa=None):
    if caixa is None:
        self.caixa = []
    else:
        self.caixa= caixa
```

Ou, mais sucinto:

```
 def __init__(self, caixa=None):
    self.caixa = [] if caixa is None else caixa
```

Comment: oi - optei por escrever outra resposta para incorporar de fato as diferenças do `=`  e do `+=` - além do problema do `[]` como argumento padrão.

Comment: Vejo que o problema era apenas meu entendimento um pouco mais aprofundado na linguagem, porém acho um pouco nociva as convenções de alguns comportamentos tendo em vista que a semântica mais natural ou mais intuitiva seja comprometida... Obrigado.

Comment: Uma caratceristica de Python é que não tem "exceções" - esse comportamento foi menos planejado, do que ser uma consequência de como a linguagem funciona. É que pra quem é iniciante não dá pra ter noção de como ela funciona de fato  - o comando "def" que cria funções é _executado_  quando um arquivo .py é importado - a exercução do comando "def" cria um objeto "função" que é uma instância de "FunctionType". Um dos atributos de uma função é seu código. Outro dos atributos é os argumentos padrão - o objeto colocado como argumetno padrão vira um atributo da Função e é o mesmo em todas as chamadas.

Comment: (incorporei o comentário acima na minha resposta - acho que nessas palavras fica claro o que acontece "por dentro")

Answer (score 1):

## O seu problema real

O seu grande problema aí é que você está usando uma lista (`[]`) como argumento padrão no método `__init__` - como a linha `def __init__(self,caixa=[]):` é executada uma única vez, essa lista é criada apenas uma vez, e uma única e mesma lista vai ser usada em **todas as instâncias** da classe `f`.

Para arrumar isso, mude seu código para:

```py
class f():
    def __init__(self,caixa=None):
        self.caixa= caixa if caixa is not None else []
```

Pronto - com essa mudança, uma nova lista é criada a cada instância.

(claro que a classe `g` precisa da mesma mudança na declaração  do `__init__`)

Essa coisa da "lista ser a mesma toda vez que o `__init__` é chamado, pode parecer estranho, mas justamente, uma característica de Python é que não tem "exceções" - esse comportamento foi menos planejado, do que ser uma consequência de como a linguagem funciona. É que pra quem é iniciante não dá pra ter noção de como ela funciona de fato - o comando "def" que cria funções é executado quando um arquivo .py é importado - a execução do comando "def" cria um objeto "function" que é uma instância de "FunctionType". Um dos atributos de uma function é seu código. Outro dos atributos é os argumentos padrão - o objeto colocado como argumento padrão vira um atributo da Função e é o mesmo em todas as chamadas.

Então, sim, o pessoal que é responsável por evoluir a linguagem sabe bem que é um comportamento anti-intuitivo, e é uma armadilha pra qualquer um que não estude a linguagem a fundo - mesmo que a pessoa tenha muita prática em outras linguagens - mas a opção foi no passado por não criar uma exceção nesses casos - e hoje nem que se pensasse diferente, não é possível mudar por conta da quebra de compatibilidade. O melhor negócio é entender essa característica e usar a seu favor. (E se uma IDE não alertar para o uso de uma lista ou um dicionário como argumento padrão, o certo era abrir um bug contra a IDE)

## O comportamento de  `a = a + b` e `a += b`

O comportamento do  `+=` é dado pelo método `__iadd__` se ele existir na classe do objeto da esquerda. Se não houver - o `__add__` é chamado (ou `__radd__` no objeto da direita) - e o resultado é identico ao uso de `x = x + y`.

Por convenção ainda, o `__iadd__` quando existe vai modificar o *próprio* objeto (self) - e o `__add__` vai criar uma outra instância.

Então, tipicamente a implementação vai ser algo como:

```
class F:
   def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
   def  __add__(self, other):
       return type(self)(valor=self.valor + other.valor)
   def __iadd__(self, other):
       self.valor += other.valor
       return self
```

No caso de listas, e outros objetos mutáveis, é exatamente o que acontece. Então `lista1 += lista2` vai modificar a lista 1 internamente, já
`lista1 = lista1 + lista2`  vai criar uma *nova* lista que é a concatenação das listas lista1 + lista2 , e guarda o resultado disso no nome `lista1`, sobre-escrevendo a referência anterior.

Se você tem alguma referência a lista1, antes da linha `lista1 = lista1 + lista2`, essa referência **não** vai ver alterações, e vai continuar apontando pra "lista1" original.

## Entendendo o seu problema baseado nessas duas coisas:

É simples: a linha
`self.listaFs[0].caixa= self.listaFs[0].caixa + ['ok']` cria uma NOVA lista que vai ficar em `a.caixa` -e então os objetos `b` e `c` ainda vão compartilhar a mesma lista- mas `a.caixa` fica sendo uma lista independente.

Enquanto que a linha:
`self.listaFs[0].caixa+= ['ok']` altera a mesma instância da lista, que está no `a.caixa` -e aí, como ela permanece compartilhada nas instâncias `b` e `c`, você vê essa modificação olhando por aquelas instâncias.

Comment: Quebrei muito a cabeça com esses comportamentos estranhos mais agora esta tudo esclarecido, obrigado.