# Receba um número inteiro na entrada, calcule e imprima a soma dos dígitos impares deste número na saída

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

Vi uma dúvida parecida e ele usou esse código, mas no meu caso eu preciso que ele some somente os números ímpares que ele receber.

Por exemplo, ao digitar `123`, ao invés de somar 1+2+3 ele deve somar 1+3 somente. Como ficaria?

```
x = int(input("Numero: "))

soma = 0

while (x != 0):
    resto = x % 10
    x = (x - resto)//10
    soma = soma + resto
print(soma)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesta questão você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
n = input()

soma = 0
for c in n:
    x = int(c)
    if x % 2 != 0:
        soma += x
print(soma)
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/viucdrar-solkarped).

Observe que neste algoritmo estão ocorrendo os seguintes fatos:

1. O algoritmo captura o valor numérico e o armazena como `string`;
2. O laço `for` percorre todos os elementos da `string` e os converte para inteiros;
3. Verifica se o inteiro é `impar` e, se for, realiza a soma deles;
4. Exibe a `soma` de todos os dígitos ímpares.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente como eu queria!

Comment: Ok! Estamos aqui para ajudar, com conteúdo de qualidade.

Answer (score 1):

Você *quase* acertou, só faltou verificar se o dígito é ímpar:

```
x = abs(int(input("Numero: ")))
soma = 0
while x != 0:
    resto = x % 10
    if resto % 2 != 0: # só adiciona à soma se for ímpar
        soma += resto
    x //= 10
```

Repare que o operador `//` retorna o resultado da divisão já desconsiderando as casas decimais, então não precisa fazer `(x - resto)//10`. Também usei `soma += resto`, que faz o mesmo que `soma = soma + resto` (para números o resultado será o mesmo, mas há casos em que faz diferença usar um ou outro, entenda melhor lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/402692/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/462653/112052)). O mesmo vale para `x //= 10`, que é o mesmo que `x = x // 10`.

Também incluí uma chamada a [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) para retornar o valor absoluto do número (sem sinal), assim o algoritmo funciona também para números negativos (pois `-19 % 10` resulta em 1, não em 9, então é mais fácil transformar o número para positivo primeiro e prosseguir daí). O código da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/462796/112052) não leva em conta esse caso, pois considera que todos os caracteres da string serão dígitos, e ao tentar converter o caractere `-` para `int`, dará erro.

Talvez você pense "*mas é só um exercício, o usuário sempre vai digitar números positivos*", mas de qualquer forma, se estou trabalhando com números, um algoritmo matemático costuma uma melhor opção do que manipular uma string. Então eu prefiro converter a string para número apenas uma vez, no início do algoritmo, e se ela não for um número válido, já dá erro ali mesmo e nem começo o algoritmo (por exemplo, se for digitado `123456789x`, a outra resposta irá percorrer todos os dígitos, e só quando chegar no `x` dará erro, já o meu código dará erro no início, e nem iniciará o algoritmo - pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas a abordagem [*fail fast*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) me parece mais apropriada para este caso - se a entrada não for um número, não há motivo para sequer começar o algoritmo).

Sem contar que eu posso digitar coisas como `+2` ou        `+2`   (com o sinal de `+` e espaços no início e no fim), que `int` consegue converter corretamente para número (tente usar o código da outra resposta, dará erro porque vai tentar converter o `+` ou o espaço para número).

Talvez eu esteja sendo muito rígido, mas se a ideia é que o usuário digite um número válido, você tem que estar preparado para verificar se de fato é um número, e só começar o algoritmo se de fato for. Não é o foco da pergunta, mas seria algo do tipo:

```
try:
    x = abs(int(input('Número: ')))
    # restante do algoritmo...
except ValueError:
    print('Não foi digitado um número')
```

---

Se quiser, também pode usar [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), assim você tem o resultado da divisão e o resto de uma só vez:

```
x = abs(int(input('Número: ')))
soma = 0
while x != 0:
    x, resto = divmod(x, 10)
    if resto % 2 != 0:
        soma += resto
```